# Android BLE scan/connect/notify

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to  developing an app to communicate with a BLE device.
I have NO experience in developing any sort of Bluetooth application using Android.
if any example source code for app can scan-connect and read some characteristic.

its hard to get a working source code

Comment: Actually Google has a [Bluetooth LE Gatt sample](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main/BluetoothLeGatt) repository on github. But I can't say that it is easy for beginners.

Comment: Some useful links:
-- https://intersog.com/blog/code/how-to-work-properly-with-bt-le-on-android/
-- https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b
-- https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Kotlin, you can do exactly what you ask for in Kotlin.

Here's an example of scanning for Bluetooth devices:

```kotlin
fun scanForBluetoothDevices() {
    val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
    }
    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
        val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
    }
    val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
    // If there are paired devices
    if (pairedDevices?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
        // Loop through paired devices
        pairedDevices.forEach { device ->
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            Log.d("Bluetooth", "Device: ${device.name}, ${device.address}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I think you are sure, I have to change to kotlin, despite that I have already started my app with java,